how does this code execute the finally block even though it's never evaluated to be true?
def divisive_recursion(n):
    try:
        if n <= 0:
            return 1
        else:
            return n + divisive_recursion(n // divisive_recursion(n - 1))
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return -1
    finally:
        if n == 2:
            print("Finally block executed for n=2")
        elif n == 1:
            print("Finally block executed for n=1")

print(divisive_recursion(5))

Here, divisive_recursion(1) results in 1 + (1 // divisive_recursion(0)), then divisive_recursion(0) returns 1 and it goes into an infinite recursion, where divisive_recursion(1) and divisive_recursion(0) gets executed repeatedly. I expected the code to give and RecursionError due to this, which it does, but the finally blocks get executed before that somehow, I know that they get executed always but for the prints to be printed n should be equal to 1 or 2, which it never does due to the infinite recursion so how come both the print statements are printed when the condition inside them is never evaluated to be True?

In one of the comments, you ask "does that mean once the program encounters the crash, it will execute all the finally blocks upward the recursion before it finally crashes".
And the answer is basically "yes".
An exception isn't really a "crash", or perhaps think of it as a controlled way of crashing.
Here is a simple example to illustrate, in this case where the exception is caught and handled:
>>> def foo(n):
...     if n == 0:
...         raise RuntimeError
...     try:
...         foo(n - 1)
...     except:
...         print(f'caught exception at {n=}')
...     finally:
...         print(f'in finally at {n=}')
... 
>>> foo(5)
caught exception at n=1
in finally at n=1
in finally at n=2
in finally at n=3
in finally at n=4
in finally at n=5

And perhaps even more clarifying, here is a case with an uncaught exception:
>>> def foo(n):
...     if n == 0:
...         raise RuntimeError
...     try:
...         foo(n - 1)
...     except ZeroDivisionError:
...         print(f'caught exception at {n=}')
...     finally:
...         print(f'in finally at {n=}')
... 
>>> foo(5)
in finally at n=1
in finally at n=2
in finally at n=3
in finally at n=4
in finally at n=5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in foo
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in foo
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in foo
  [Previous line repeated 2 more times]
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in foo
RuntimeError


The right way to think about this is that each recursive call to divisive_recursion has it's own value of n it's being called with.
Think about it this way: When you call divisive_recursion(1), something happens - for the purpose of this question, it's not important what, and the fact that it has a recursive call is inconsequential. The only thing that is important for the sake of this answer is that in this call, you have n=1. Whatever happens in the try block eventually raised a RecursionError. For argument's sake, you could have had an except: block to better visualize this (although that's generally a not a great practice). Once the try block terminates (by raising an error in this case), the finally block is executed. Since n is 1 (it was never modified during the try block, so if the function was called with 1 it will remain 1), the elif block is entered, and its contents are executed.

what about n == 2? is that also executed the same way?

@Puna yup, similar logic applies for that too. I didn't run through it with your example of n=5, but from reading the code it seems as though it should pass through n=2 at some point of the recursion.

does that mean if conditions of any value upto 5 will get printed if they existed? how does that work, isn't it only the n value before the crash that get's printed? does that mean once the program encounters the crash, it will execute all the finally blocks upward the recursion before it finally crashes?

@Puna yup - the "inner" most function call will raise the expectation, and it will propagate "upwards" through all the callers. If any of them do anything in their finally blocks, you'll see it.
